# Os X Lion 10.7.4 mds: (Error) Server: mdsync launch failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

Tags: macos, spotlight

Im getting this message over and over again in my console:

```
27.06.12 18:05:31,541 mds: (Error) Server: mdsync launch failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
27.06.12 18:05:31,541 mds: (Error) Server: mdsync launch failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
27.06.12 18:05:31,541 mds: (Error) Server: mdsync launch failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
27.06.12 18:05:31,541 mds: (Error) Server: mdsync launch failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

I assume something is bad with mds/spotlight service's. But what exactly? Anybody got any ideas? I tried to re-enable indexing, unload/load md related jobs through launchctl, still getting that error message...

**[UPDATE]**

After an hour the message stopped - but oddly enough those errors stopped, now the console is spitting those. I cant't find any info about mdworker errors...

```
27.06.12 18:48:49,059 com.apple.mdworker.isolation.0: warning: invalid bfrange: string length is not a multiple of 2.
```

Comment: Do you have any *actual* problems using Spotlight or is it just this error you're seeing?

Comment: Not that i am aware off - it works. I mean i type something and it finds it the way it always did. My computer is howerver a lot of faster since i Purged all of that indexing files and reindexed turning backup drives and other unnecessary places.